# invalid column name RDLC Report Viewer says while populating data to data source using multiple data sources

Tags: vb.net, reporting, desktop-application, rdlc

I am trying to print an RDLC report that gets data from multiple data sources. The first data source is filled with data while the other data source gives the following error
"Invalid Column Name '*INV123*'"
The code for filling the data sources is as follows:

```
            frmInvoiceReport.DataTable_InvoiceTableAdapter.Fill(frmInvoiceReport.SIS_DBDataSet.DataTable_Invoice)
            frmInvoiceReport.DataTable_InvoiceInfoTableAdapter1.Fill(frmInvoiceReport.SIS_DBDataSet.DataTable_InvoiceInfo)



            'The DataSet created.
            Dim myConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(cs)
            Dim myDA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [View_Invoice_Details] Where InvID = " & txtID.Text, myConnection)
            Dim myDS As New DataSet
            myDA.Fill(myDS, "DataTable_Invoice")


            Dim myDa2 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [View_InvoiceInfo] Where InvoiceNo = " & txtInvoiceNo.Text, myConnection)
            Dim myDs2 As New DataSet
            myDa2.Fill(myDs2, "DataTable_InvoiceInfo")

            frmInvoiceReport.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
            Dim DtSrc As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("SIS_DBDataSet", myDS.Tables("DataTable_Invoice"))
            Dim DtSrc2 As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("SIS_DBDataSet", myDs2.Tables("DataTable_InvoiceInfo"))

            frmInvoiceReport.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(DtSrc)
            frmInvoiceReport.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(DtSrc2)

            frmInvoiceReport.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

            frmInvoiceReport.ShowDialog()
```

I am not sure where the error arises. I have debugged the code and it catches an exception saying that the column name is invalid. I need a quick fix for that.

Comment: Are you sure your fields on the report are referencing the correct `DataSet`? Could you not just use one `DataSet`, and add the multiple `DataTable`s to the single `DataSet`?

Comment: In fact, there are two queries for two separate views, one view populates a Tablix the other populates individual fields separately. Can you please show me an example of code.